# what is the difference between attributes[0] and attributes.item(0) in javascript dom?

Tags: javascript

I am beginner in javascript and came to know that we can use `element.attributes[0]` and `element.attributes.item(0)` to call the first attribute in html element.
Is there any difference behind the scene ? If no, what is better to use ?

Comment: Shouldn't be any difference. If you have to support *extremely* old browsers, then the array syntax wouldn't work but I very much doubt that's the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one other than that `item` is a method call. The result is the same, other than that `element.attributes[0]` will give you `undefined` for an attribute that isn't present, but `element.item(0)` will give you `null`.

```js
const ex = document.querySelector("span");
console.log(ex.attributes[0]);
console.log(ex.attributes.item(0));
```

```html
<span>x</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

They are interchangable. The array notation is a syntactic sugar, and it might be a bit misleading, because `element.attributes` is not an `Array`, but a `NodeList`, so the usual array methods do not work on it. I think, that the choice between them is up to personal preference.